# CoreData Widget not updating after initial run

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data, widgetkit

I've been trying to update the data in my widget that is fetched from CoreData, but the Widget only refreshes when I run the project for the first time.

Neither the getTimeline, nor the getSnapshot functions are being called when I call the following function from the app when the data is saved.

> WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents
import CoreData

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    
    let subjects = getData()

    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
       SimpleEntry(date: Date(), subjects: [], configuration: ConfigurationIntent())
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        print("Snapshot called")
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), subjects: subjects, configuration: configuration)
        completion(entry)
    }
    
    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        print("TimeLine called")
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), subjects: subjects, configuration: configuration)
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .never)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let subjects: [Subject]
    let configuration : ConfigurationIntent
}
```

If it helps, I had written some similar code that worked perfectly before on another similar app. I tried uninstalling the app and downloading it again, changing the timeline policy from .never to .atEnd but it didn't work.

I don't have any user configurable options for the widget so I tried removing the ConfigurationIntent references in the code, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so after searching through some code on GitHub I found an answer.

```
import Combine

class AppObserver {
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        NotificationCenter.Publisher(center: .default, name: .NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: context)
            .sink { _ in
                WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
}
```

I added this app observer and then passed it into the main app

```
    let observer = AppObserver(context: DataController.shared.container.viewContext)
```

This seemed to solve the issue for me. Also, try deleting the data stored in CoreData and testing with new data, that was partly the problem with my code

Comment: Just remember that there is an allowance for reloading timelines, it usually doesn’t apply when the app is in the foreground but Apple can be very picky, reloading at every change of context can be very risky, try when the scene changes, it will lump all the context changes into 1 when the app goes into the background for example.